# Several containers on same host addressed with similar port

Tags: windows, docker, networking

I have a client which uses hard coded port 8090.
I would like a machine A to run 3 instances of this client, so each client address different server.
Each of the 3 servers is hosted in a dedicated container, and the 3 containers are hosted on machine B with IP 8.8.4.4.
The problem is that each client addresses to 8.8.4.4:8090, but I would like to route each client to the specific container.

I think that the solution should be something as follows:
Each client will use a specific IP address e.g 8.8.4.1, 8.8.4.2, 8.8.4.3.
Somehow I will map on machine A IPs 8.8.4.1, 8.8.4.2, 8.8.4.3 should be mapped to localhost.
Have a proxy server that will forward from 8.8.4.1:8090 to 8.8.4.4:1000.
Port forward at container c1 from port 1000 to 8090.
Do the same for the other 2 IPs.

My main gap is how to map from IP 8.8.4.1 back to the localhost so that the proxy server will understand that it should forward it to 8.8.4.4:1000.

A diagram. A, B are both windows machines.
c1, c2, c3 are the containers.

         `A                                              B
+--------------------+                          +--------------------+
|                    |                          |       1000:8090    |
|                    |                          |    +----------+    |
|                    |                          |    |   c1     |    |
|               +----------------------------------->+          |    |
|                    |                          |    +----------+    |
|                    |                          |       2000:8090    |
|                    |                          |    +----------+    |
|               +----------------------------------->+   c2     |    |
|                    |                          |    |          |    |
|                    |                          |    +----------+    |
|                    |                          |       3000:8090    |
|                    |                          |    +----------+    |
|               +----------------------------------->+    c3    |    |
|                    |                          |    |          |    |
|                    |                          |    +----------+    |
+--------------------+                          +--------------------+`
``

Your thoughts and ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have a look for `nginx`, next is sample configure for routing.

Let's suppose client all run on machineA, and machineA has the ip 8.8.4.5, also nginx run on machineA:

**Part of nginx.conf**:

```
stream {
    upstream server1 {
        server 8.8.4.4:1000;
    }

    upstream server2 {
        server 8.8.4.4:2000;
    }

    upstream server3 {
        server 8.8.4.4:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8090;
        server_name nginx1;
        proxy_pass server1;
    }

    server {
        listen 8090;
        server_name nginx2;
        proxy_pass server2;
    }

    server {
        listen 8090;
        server_name nginx3;
        proxy_pass server3;
    }
}
```

Then add next to hosts file:

```
8.8.4.5 nginx1
8.8.4.5 nginx2
8.8.4.5 nginx3
```

And clients use next to connect:

- client1: nginx1:8090
- client2: nginx2:8090
- client3: nginx3:8090

If you do not want to use vhost of nginx, you can directly use multiple ip on one network card, then you do not need set hosts file. See [this](https://tunecomp.net/windows-10-multiple-ip-addresses/).

**PS:** Of course if your clients have ability to bind to different ips just as I thought at first, something like this:

```
tcp_client.bind(('8.8.4.1', xxx))
tcp_client.connect((server_ip, server_port))
```

Then it's also ok to use `remote_addr` to distinguish connection, like next:

```
stream {
    upstream server1 {
        server 8.8.4.4:1000;
    }

    upstream server2 {
        server 8.8.4.4:2000;
    }

    upstream server3 {
        server 8.8.4.4:3000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8090;

        if ($remote_addr ~* "8.8.4.1")
        {
            proxy_pass server1;
        }

        if ($remote_addr ~* "8.8.4.2")
        {
            proxy_pass server2;
        }

        if ($remote_addr ~* "8.8.4.3")
        {
            proxy_pass server3;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The nginx solution looks like what I need. I want to run the nginx on machine A. How to configure that requests for 8.8.4.1 will be directed from machine A to machine A? Should I modify the hosts file? If I'll do that, will the nginx know that the request was directed to 8.8.4.1 and not localhost?

Comment: I guess I have some misunderstand for your question, so I update now. With new update, nginx listen on different vhost(or ip), then your client could connect to different vhost or ip, and finally route you to same ip, but different ports.